# Json Array Same Object Duplicate Times

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I want to get random photos from unsplash and show in my app. Here's the request url I have formed (works with api_key). [random photos from unsplash](https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?client_id=api_key&orientation&count=30.)

I have created my model class according to this structure with getters and setters(omitted) like below:

```
public class UnsplashImages {

public String imageId;
public String rawImg;
public String fullImg;
public String regularImg;
public String smallImg;
public String thumbImg;

public UnsplashImages() {}

public UnsplashImages(String imageId, String rawImg, String fullImg, String regularImg, String smallImg, String thumbImg) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.rawImg = rawImg;
    this.fullImg = fullImg;
    this.regularImg = regularImg;
    this.smallImg = smallImg;
    this.thumbImg = thumbImg;
}
}
```

According to [the docs](https://unsplash.com/documentation#get-a-random-photo.), this endpoint will return only one image unless count is specified in request url, so I have added count to be max value (30).

This is the json response I am getting for count value > 1:

```
[
{
id: "7kWEtC4TZlE",
created_at: "2018-02-12T17:28:19-05:00",
updated_at: "2018-05-18T14:03:44-04:00",
width: 3980,
height: 4975,
color: "#FAC9A7",
description: null,
urls: {
 raw: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518474436123-0e44861523f7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI4ODUzfQ&s=6d9ef54c8c96afc3fbd6cd9aca9e2cf6",
 full: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518474436123-0e44861523f7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI4ODUzfQ&s=e12d5951d3907a1917eb9c1a1c2b67e4",
 regular: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518474436123-0e44861523f7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI4ODUzfQ&s=da9be90c5000190c773f31969059fdae",
 small: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518474436123-0e44861523f7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI4ODUzfQ&s=7630a6850ad1e87dfd580f5066482ee5",
 thumb: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518474436123-0e44861523f7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=200&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI4ODUzfQ&s=fb527398e3ee3e8c411674fd0a65ce5b"
},
links: {},
categories: [ ],
sponsored: false,
likes: 54,
liked_by_user: false,
current_user_collections: [ ],
slug: null,
user: {},
exif: {},
location: {},
views: 262012,
downloads: 876
},
 {}, 
 .
 .
 .
}
```

In my fragment I have done json parsing like below:

```
String s = Constants.RANDOM_PHOTOS + "&count=30";
    Log.d(TAG, "Unsplash Misc URL:\t" + s);

    AndroidNetworking.get(s)
            .addHeaders("Accept-Version", "v1")
            .addHeaders("CLIENT-ID", Constants.UNSPLASH_ACCESS_KEY)
            .setTag("Unsplash Scifi req")
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .getResponseOnlyFromNetwork()
            .build()
            .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Un-Response:\t" + response.toString());
                    if (response != null){
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.toString());

                            UnsplashImages images = new UnsplashImages();
                            for (int m = 0; m < jsonArray.length(); m++){
                                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(m);

                                images.setImageId(object.getString("id"));

                                JSONObject urls = object.getJSONObject("urls");

                                images.setRawImg(urls.getString("raw"));
                                images.setFullImg(urls.getString("full"));
                                images.setRegularImg(urls.getString("regular"));
                                images.setSmallImg(urls.getString("small"));
                                images.setThumbImg(urls.getString("thumb"));

                                objectList.add(images);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError anError) {

                }
            });
```

Here's the adapter code:

```
public class MiscAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WallpaperItemViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = MiscAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private final Context context;
private List<Object> itemsList;

private UnsplashImages unsplashImages;

public MiscAdapter(Context context, List<Object> itemsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
}

@Override
public WallpaperItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.wallpaper_items_layout, parent, false);
    return new WallpaperItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final WallpaperItemViewHolder viewholder, final int position) {
    unsplashImages = (UnsplashImages) itemsList.get(position);

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(unsplashImages.getRegularImg())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.drawer_header_trimmed)
            .into(viewholder.wallpaperItemImg);

    viewholder.favoriteWP_IV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Favorites favorites = new Favorites();
            favorites.setFavoritesId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            favorites.setLargeImgURL(unsplashImages.getRegularImg());
            favorites.setPreviewImgURL(unsplashImages.getRegularImg());
            favorites.save();
            Log.d(TAG, "Fav id:\t" + favorites.getId());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Added to Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    viewholder.setWallPaper_TV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);

            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(((UnsplashImages) itemsList.get(position)).getRegularImg())
                    .into(new Target() {
                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                            try {
                                wpm.setBitmap(bitmap);
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Your New Wallpaper Has Been Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap Load Failed");
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Could Not Set Wallpaper...Choose Another", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Prep to Load Bitmap");
                        }
                    });

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (itemsList == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return itemsList.size();
}
}
```

The images show in the recyclerview list but instead of different items, the same image is shown 30 times in the list. Is this a problem with my json parsing or something else?.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for your time. I have fixed this by declaring the new instance of my model class inside the for loop like below:

```
for (int m = 0; m < jsonArray.length(); m++) {
                                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(m);

                                UnsplashImages images = new UnsplashImages(); // this here
                                images.setImageId(object.getString("id"));

                                JSONObject urls = object.getJSONObject("urls");

                                images.setRawImg(urls.getString("raw"));
                                images.setFullImg(urls.getString("full"));
                                images.setRegularImg(urls.getString("regular"));
                                images.setSmallImg(urls.getString("small"));
                                images.setThumbImg(urls.getString("thumb"));

                                objectList.add(images);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
```

For future observers, take note. Thank you.